# How do you show this limit is zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} \dfrac{e^{-a^{2}/(4t)}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}}$, with $a > 0$.

I've tried bounding it in various ways and of course Lhospitals rule...but to no avail.

Comment: FYI, this isn't homework and I did look for a while to see if this question was already posted. Didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: its $$e^{-\frac{a^2}4t}$$ or $$e^{-\frac{a^2}{4t}}$$?

Comment: $t$ is in the denominator...I'll try and edit it real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

See if you can relate your limit to the following computation:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{\frac{1}{x}}\sqrt x>\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\infty$$

In other words, notice that $\sqrt{4\pi t}>4\pi t$ when $t$ is small and positive.  This should help you bound your limit with:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{4\pi t}}{e^{\frac{a^2}{4t}}}$$

Now use L'Hospital.

Comment: Got it, that's what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty} c_1\frac{\sqrt t}{e^{c_2t}}$$
with positive constants $c_1, c_2$. You may already know that the exponential "grows faster" than any polynomial, therefore the limit is $0$

Comment: I don't think so, you're missing a $t$ in the denominator.

Comment: I substituted $t$ with $\frac 1t$. That turns $e^{-\frac{a^2}{4t}}$ into $e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}t}=\frac1{e^{\frac {a^2}4 t}}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$ to $\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sqrt t$. Now let $c_2=\frac{a^2}{4}>0$ and $c_1=\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi}}$.

Comment: Oh, I missed the t going to infinity. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Putting $\frac1t=u,$

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} \dfrac{e^{\frac{-a^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}}$$

$$=\lim_{u \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{e^{\frac{-a^2u}4}}{\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi}u}}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi}}\lim_{u \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac u{e^{\frac{a^2u}4}}\text{ which is of the form }\frac\infty\infty $$

So, applying  l'Hospital's rule,

$$\lim_{u \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac u{e^{\frac{a^2u}4}}=\lim_{u \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac1{\frac{a^2}4\cdot e^{\frac{a^2u}4}} =0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}{{\rm e}^{-a^{2}/\left(4t\right)} \over \sqrt{4\pi t}}
=
\delta\left(a\right)
$$

$\delta\left(a\right)$ is the "Dirac delta function". It is NOT an ordinary function. It's a distribution. It is widely used for physicists. It was introduced, in 1930, by P. A. M. Dirac in his famous book ( [http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Quantum-Mechanics-International-Monographs/dp/0198520115/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1376374803&sr=1-1&keywords=dirac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198520115) ).

See, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html